# Error download mysqlclient on Windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, terminal, python, mysql

After type this code in Terminal `pip install mysqlclient` I recieve this error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'f:\pycharm\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hjic4wc3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -If:\pycharm\python\include -If:\pycharm\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\ATLMFC\include"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\pycharm\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hjic4wc3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

And this is the whole Terminal window

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'f:\pycharm\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hjic4wc3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -If:\pycharm\python\include -If:\pycharm\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\ATLMFC\include"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\pycharm\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8c6ksaj2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hjic4wc3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm new so I don't know what is happening:(.I hopes you guys can find out.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new so I don't know what is happening.

Based on the fact the error code indicates that 'mysql.h' is not on your system.

> Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

It means you have not installed the [MySQL Connector C++](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) on your system.